# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php, hooks, actions, headers, wp-redirect

So I have a form on one page, which is submitting to `admin-post.php`, then there is a function in functions.php which is processing the form. It stores the input field data to database and then after that it should redirect the user to another page. It stores the information in database, but it is not redirecting. The problem is that it says

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Code:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post">
        <input id="user_name" type="text" name="yourname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
        <input id="user_email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        <button id="button" type="button" name="submit">Go</button>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login_form">
        </form>
```

functions.php

```
function prefix_send_email_to_admin() {
    /**
     * At this point, $_GET/$_POST variable are available
     *
     * We can do our normal processing here
     */

    // Sanitize the POST field
    // Generate email content
    // Send to appropriate email
        function my_print_error(){

            global $wpdb;

            if($wpdb->last_error !== '') :

                $str   = htmlspecialchars( $wpdb->last_result, ENT_QUOTES );
                $query = htmlspecialchars( $wpdb->last_query, ENT_QUOTES );

                print "<div id='error'>
                <p class='wpdberror'><strong>WordPress database error:</strong> [$str]<br />
                <code>$query</code></p>
                </div>";

            endif;

        }
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                global $wpdb;

                $wpdb->show_errors();

                $table = 'username';
                $data = array(
                    'name' => $_POST['yourname']
                );

                $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

                if($success){
                    echo 'data has been save' ;
                                wp_redirect("http://example.design/projects/webdev/wordpress_nepal/");

                                exit;
                }
                else {
                    my_print_error();
                }

            }
    //  wp_redirect("http://example.design/projects/webdev/wordpress_nepal/");

}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'prefix_send_email_to_admin' );
```

I tried both, `wp_loaded` hook after some googling and my original `admin_post_nopriv_login_form` but it doesn't help.

Comment: You can't print output at `wp_loaded` it's too early. That's what the warning is.

Comment: @JacobPeattie As I understand, `wp_loaded` should work because it firesb efore the headers are already sent which is when it's too late. But then which hook should I use?

Comment: No, the problem is outputting anything before the headers are sent. WordPress is trying to send headers but there's already been output to the screen, which messes it up.

Comment: Then how do I redirect before headers are sent?

Comment: A redirect isn't output, they've got nothing to do with each other. It's the `echo 'data has been save' ;` and `print "<div id='error'>` lines that are causing this specific message to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `template_redirect` action instead of `wp_loaded`. 
It's a good practice add `die();` after `wp_redirect()` to.

Comment: And the line `echo 'data has been save' ;` right before the redirect should be removed.